# PHP insert into sql with array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, amazon-web-services

the following code works to grab a return value from a php run_instance script. However, the value returned ($instanceIds) is in an array format. I need to insert these values, along with the userName and serverName into an sql database in separate rows for each value that is contained within the $instanceIds array. However, where I am getting confused is that I don't know how to insert the $instanceIds into the database in a way so that the userName and serverName are inserted over and over again until the end of the array. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<?php
session_start();
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

include 'mysql_connect.php';

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("database",$con);

// Describe the now-running instance to get the public URL
$result = $ec2Client->describeInstances(array(
    'InstanceIds' => $instanceIds,
));


$server_record = mysql_query("INSERT INTO server_tbl (userName, serverName, serverId, isRunning) VALUES ('$name', 'runtest', '$instanceIds', 'X'");

print_r($instanceIds);

?>
```

Comment: you must iterate (loop) over the content of $result and issue an 'INSERT ...' statement for each value in the array

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. Switch to prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($instanceIds as $instanceId) {
    $server_record = mysql_query("INSERT INTO server_tbl "
        . "(userName, serverName, serverId, isRunning) "
        . "VALUES ('$name', 'runtest', '$instanceId', 'X'");
}
```

Comment: this approach doesn't work. The code runs fine without the foreach in there, but as soon as the foreach is inserted it breaks and just displays a white screen.

Comment: Sorry, I put in too many concatenation symbols. I fixed my answer

Comment: It works, it is just inserting $instanceID as "Array" Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind. Figured it out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What was the problem? Maybe I should update my answer once more.

Answer (score 0):

1. You really, really should not use mysql_real_escape_string() or mysql_query() or any of the mysql functions. They are deprecated, insecure, and will be removed from PHP in the future, breaking your entire app. Please save yourself and your users a lot of headache by using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.
2. Use a foreach loop to iterate over the array.

   ```
    foreach ($instanceIds as $id){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO server_tbl (userName, serverName, serverId, isRunning) VALUES ('$name', 'runtest', '$id', 'X')";

        //do your insert here with the above SQL statement, depending on whether you use mysqli or PDO
   ```